# Xcode Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, xcode

i am facing a problem with my Xcode and my visual studio code
if i want to create a new project the simulator and the code runs and works
but when i tried to open an old projects it shows me this error
i tried everything and i searched on youtube asked the AI bots nothing worked with me
any helpful tips please
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHeYd.png)